# TeeChart Evaluation Version says expired but I just installed it. Why

Tags: .net, evaluation, teechart

I'm excited to try the DirectX accelerated TeeChart for my signal processing application. I've  downloaded and installed the evaluation version but no components are available in the VS toolbox and all the charts in the demo app are stamped "expired". Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the TeeChart design-time license is correctly installed on your computer. Please follow the steps I explained [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=7677) to do so.

If components are still not visible at Visual Studio's toolbox you can add them manually as explained [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=7780).

Finally, we also published a [new maintenance release](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14662). You might be interested in installing it and check if it solves any of your problems.

Comment: I succeeded in getting the TeeChart controls into the toolbox but they all still indicate that the evaluation has expired. I installed it for the first time yesterday. Is there some sort of "reset" we can do?

Comment: @user3295848 have you followed the steps in the links I posted? As explained there, if the design-time developer license is not installed in your machine you can do so running TeeRegister tool, which you'll find at the client download area.